# How to combine js and html response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unobtrusive-javascript

fellows.
I have a simple link that have a property **data-remote => true**.

Everything works fine: when I click the link I get a js alert msg from server.
But I want that a server checks some condition and sends a js alert msg in one case and starts a file download in another case.

Is It possible?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can change like this

```
def some_method

  if file_download
    download_file
    response = 'downlaod'
  else
    response = 'alert'
  end

 respond_to do |format|
   format.js
 end
end
```

**some_method.js.erb**

```
<% if response == 'alert' %>
alert('hello');
<%else %>
//your code
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But Does It really work? Your approach returns a binary file content to a client but doest start a download.